# SwiftUI – Markdown styling issues with MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I ran the following code on iOS and MacOS and found a discrepancy.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
    
    var text: AttributedString {
        let markdown = "[This is a link](https://queue.community)"
        var attributedString: AttributedString = try! AttributedString(markdown: markdown)
        let fullStringRange = attributedString.startIndex..<attributedString.endIndex
        attributedString[fullStringRange].foregroundColor = .red
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

When I ran the code targetting iOS, it correctly overrides the link color to red, but when I target MacOS, it stays the default color of blue. I need the ability to override foregroundcColor on MacOS. (See Images)

[iOS rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og5s8.jpg)

[Macos rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q53a.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQzsg.jpg

Please explain how I can do this: it is core functionality.

I have tried using mergeAttributes with no luck. I have also tried using replace attributes but that overwrites the entire link and I can't find a way to keep the link and change the color with it.

Comment: You could use just `attributedString.foregroundColor = .red` without the range settings.
However your code works well for me, on ios16 and macos13.4 using Xcode 14.3.
 Tested on real devices, not previews. What system are you using?

Comment: I've tried both without the range settings as well. I'm using iOS16.4 and macOS 13.2.  Can you try on macOS 13.2 and see if you can reproduce?

Comment: sorry I can't do that, I only have macOS 13.4. But maybe someone else could try on different macos to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I upgraded to macos 13.3 and it fixed the problem. I will change my minimum deployment to that. Thank you so much!! If you answer that I will upvote it

Comment: thanks, but it's ok, you got going again, good enough for me.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Please write an answer. This will allow warfα to accept it and anybody else looking for an answer to the same question will be able to see it easily.

Comment: @Warfa Alternatively, you can answer your own question and then accept it.

Comment: In fact, it would be better id @Warfa answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my answer.

You could use just `attributedString.foregroundColor = .red` without the range settings.

However your code works well, on ios16 and macos13.4 using Xcode 14.3. I tested it on real devices, not previews.

So upgrade your macOS > 13.3